# Send jwt token by header in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

I want to send a `JWT token` in a header to launch a link in Flutter, but it's not working in `iOS`

Everything is working fine in Android, but in iOS, the header is not being set and the link is not working correctly because I am not authorized. When I try an HTTP request, I get the correct response, but I want to launch the link. If I set the token in the body, the link becomes too long and iOS will not launch it but in android work good

What can I do?

**My code:**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
String authorization = await prefs.get("Authorization");
String url = '${Constants.BASE_API_URL}/en/MobileIOSPayment?Amount=$amount&GatewayKey=$selectedGateWay&CurrencyKey=USD&RequestedClient=mobileapp';
Map<String, String> map = {
  "authorization": "$authorization"
};

if (await canLaunch(url)) {
  await launch(url, headers: map);
} else{
  print('can not launch');
}
```

I tried with new api to use token in body but as i said link becomes too long and print 'can not launch'